# Whats it called

Tags: java

Ok so i am a noobie at Java as many of those editing my questions know, but im learning YAY!! now i have three classes a main class (Gun.class) and two sub classes (gunopen) and (gunopenboard) what i want to research so i don't post like 50 totally noobie questions is:

how do i get the main class(Gun) to call the first class (gunopen) and when that finishes (also I'm assuming i will need a value to be returned from (gunopen) but i don't know) call the second class (gunopenboard). I have no idea what this is called or anything so im not going to ask much just a good tutorial website something so i can study how to do the above!! thanks guys!!

Comment: [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: Please write a better title for your question.

Comment: You need to start right from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: if you want to start from java,beside the tutorial mentioned above will strongly suggest **Head First Java Series**, its really a good book with beginner perspective.

Comment: be careful of what you refer to as a `subclass`

Comment: Hilarious question title of the day award...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Coming to your question , In your main () method in Gun class  you can instantiate objects of gunopen using new keyword in java and call the appropriate method and  then you can instantiate the object of the second class gunopenboard and call the appropriate method .

Answer (score 1):

Classes do not start, or finish, or call other classes.  A method in one class can can invoke a method on an instance of another class, or can invoke a static method of the other class without an instance, however.  The syntax for this should be about the first thing you learn.

My advice: continue the Java tutorial, or buy an introductory book and complete it, before asking questions here.  It doesn't hurt us any, but it's not a good use of *your* time to post questions like this when you could have flipped ten pages and gained the understanding you need even to understand the answers you'd get.